# Declaração de char na memoria

Tags: arquitetura-computadores

Galera se declaro um char exemplo : char a ; , ele tem apenas 1 byte de tamanho , e supondo que ele esta em uma arquitetura de 32 bits , não teria espaço de endereçamento perdido ,  3 bytes do endereço não ficariam livres e apenas 1 ocupado?

Comment: Leia a resposta na pergunta original. Não adianta você ficar perguntando a mesma coisa. Preste atenção na resposta, já está tudo lá. Endereço é endereço, dado é dado, não confunda os dois. Fiz até uma analogia para entender a diferença entre eles. Endereço não ocupa espaço a não ser que ele seja armazenado em algum lugar, mas aí é um dado, que por acaso é um endereço de memória.

Comment: Discordo que seja duplicata, na outra pergunta a dúvida era se cada byte era endereçado ou não, aqui a dúvida é se o uso de uma variável menor que o espaço de endereçamento "desperdiça espaço" ou não (i.e. se um endereço de 4 bytes referencia um dado de 1 byte, ficamos com 3 bytes que a princípio não podem ser endereçados). P.S. A menos que **eu próprio** esteja me confundindo aqui, o que é bem provável - não domino muito bem o assunto...

Comment: Porque tanta duplicata?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está confundindo [**endereçamento**](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endere%C3%A7o_(mem%C3%B3ria)) com [**alinhamento**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment) (o que é razoável, eu próprio 10 minutos atrás também estava confuso). Uma coisa é você determinar qual o tamanho de cada endereço, i.e. se você tem uma variável, registrador, etc que armazena um endereço, quantos bytes distintos essa variável consegue representar. Outra, é determinar *o que* exatamente está sendo representado - um byte individual? um conjunto de X bytes? Etc.

### Endereçamento

Pense na memória do computador como uma longa lista de bytes:

```
3f  79  bf  34  aa  60  14  b0  6d  68  c4  5c  1a  21  59  e7  ...
0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  ...
```

E digamos que você queira se referir a um desses bytes, digamos ao 6º (índice 5, contém o valor 0x60). Você vai precisar guardar esse endereço em algum lugar. Digamos que você use variáveis de 1 byte somente para guardar endereços. Então em algum lugar da sua memória existirá um dado ocupando 1 byte com o valor 0x05:

```
3f  79  bf  34  aa  60  14  b0  6d  68  c4  5c  1a  21  59  e7  ... 8a  9a  05  dd  c3
0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  ... X-2 X-1 X   X+1 X+2
                                                                            ^
```

Essa seria uma "arquitetura de 8 bits". É fácil perceber que nesse caso o tamanho de memória suportada seria minúsculo - apenas 256 bytes são endereçáveis... Mas e se em vez de usar 1 byte pra armazenar endereços você passasse a usar 2 bytes?

```
3f  79  bf  34  aa  60  14  b0  6d  68  c4  5c  1a  21  59  e7  ... 8a  00  05  dd  c3
0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  ... X-1 X   X+1 X+2 X+3
                                                                        ^^^^^^^
```

Essa seria uma "arquitetura de 16 bits". Agora você pode endereçar até 65536 bytes diferentes, mas cada endereço ocupa 2 bytes em vez de 1. Veja no exemplo acima, como que o endereço da sua variável agora não se refere ao dado todo (0x00 0x05) mas sim à primeira parte dele (0x00). A segunda parte (0x05) não está diretamente referenciada, mas está *implícito* pela arquitetura de 16 bits que se um dado representa um endereço, então ele deve ocupar 2 bytes, começando por aquele que está sendo referenciado (X).

(e abrindo um parêntese, note que poderíamos representar esse endereço tanto por 0x00 0x05 quanto por 0x05 0x00; o uso de um ou outro é que caracteriza uma arquitetura *big endian* ou *little endian*)

Se você estiver programando numa linguagem de nível mais baixo, como C, você pode inclusive fazer coisas "ilegais", como tentar acessar X+1 diretamente (0x05). O resultado seria imprevisível, "catastrófico" talvez, mas a culpa seria sua por não seguir as convenções da sua arquitetura (uma vez que o "endereço" em X+1 é 0x05 0xdd, que pode apontar para uma região de memória inválida).

### Alinhamento

Agora imagine que em vez da memória estamos falando de um disco rígido, que pode ter terabytes ou mesmo petabytes ou além:

```
76           4a           37            9a  9b  5b  fe  60  b0  f9  3b  14  d1  3e  62  3a
253050123000 253050123001 253050123002  ...
```

Nesse caso seria muito pouco prático endereçar cada byte individual do disco - primeiro porque isso não faz muito sentido, dificilmente alguém vai querer acessar "o byte no endereço X" fora do contexto de um arquivo, por exemplo; segundo porque, para suportar discos cada vez maiores, seriam necessários endereços bem grandes, o que desperdiça espaço. A solução então é fazer com que nem todo byte seja [diretamente] endereçável, mas dividir o sistema de arquivos em blocos - ou *clusters* - com um tamanho fixo para cada bloco, e em vez de dizer "o arquivo armazenado no byte X até o Y" dizemos "o arquivo armazenado no *bloco* X". Nesse caso, o Sistema Operacional sabe que para chegar ao arquivo é necessário multiplicar o índice do bloco pelo tamanho de cada bloco.

A memória do computador, pelo que eu presumo (como disse, até pouco tempo atrás isso também me confundia) não sofre alinhamento por padrão. Algumas aplicações podem alinhar seus dados para melhor gerenciamento. Por exemplo, eu notei que na JVM cada objeto sempre ocupa um mínimo de 24 bytes, e cresce sempre de 8 em 8 bytes (i.e. não dá pra ter um objeto com 27 bytes, por exemplo, ou é 24 ou é 32). Esses sistemas específicos podem optar por usar menos bytes para representar cada endereço, em troca de não poder ter todos os bytes da memória diretamente endereçáveis. É um *tradeoff* que pode ou não fazer sentido, dependendo do caso.

### Conclusão

Respondendo então sua pergunta, não há desperdício pois se o seu `char` ocupou 1 byte, os 3 bytes à sua frente (e atrás) continuam disponíveis para guardar outros dados e outras variáveis, e esses dados também são diretamente endereçáveis. Se uma região de memória está "ocupada" ou não depende somente do alinhamento que o sistema dá pra ela, se algum.

Nota: Essa é uma explicação simplificada, que não leva em consideração indireções nem [memória virtual](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mem%C3%B3ria_virtual). Na prática, a gestão da memória física é um tantinho mais complicada que "o endereço X aponta pro X-ésimo byte na memória". Felizmente, do ponto de vista do programador, isso *normalmente* acontece de forma transparente - o SO dá ao programador a ilusão de que a memória inteira está à sua disposição, e cada coisa está no lugar que você colocou. Toda a "mágica" acontece por debaixo dos panos, pelo menos quando se está programando aplicações normais e não coisas mais baixo nível - como componentes do próprio SO.